# How to Access Media or Resource files in Windows Phone 8

Tags: file-io, windows-phone-8

My WP8 application requirement is to access media or resource files or any office or pdf files in windows phone 8 so that I can attach it in my mail. There are certain API's like MailMessage which provides attachment property, but here I want the user the option to click on a button if require any attachment and then access the necessary files in windows phone system, and return the file path of that resource.

Is this possible??..

Also if possible what are the necessray capabilities I need to define in my App?.

Also I am a little new to windows phone 8 development, so if any snippets or links available for how to access these resource files would also be great.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The only data you can access is anything exposed as a Chooser (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769543%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for more details). You cannot access any specific files that the user has saved on the Phone (i.e. no PDF, no Office docs etc.), but you can get individual photos (as per the Choosers doc above).